# Insert google ads after certain item counts in a wordpress post

Tags: php, wordpress, loops, insert, ads

I have the following loop in my wordpress theme which shows all attached images in a post. What i want to do is to insert a google ads code after 3 attachements in a post.

```
      <?php function show_attachments(){
        global $post;
        while( have_posts () ){
            the_post();
            $post_id = $post -> ID
            ?>
            <div class="featimg"   >
                <div class="img">
                    <?php
                    $img_src = wp_get_attachment_image_src(  $post_id  , 'full' );
                    echo '<img src="'.$img_src[0].'" alt="" />';


                    ?>
                </div>
            </div>
        <?php
        }
    }
$layout = new LBSidebarResizer( 'attachment' );
$layout -> render_frontend( 'show_attachments' );
?>
```

I guess I have to do something similair to this:

```
      <?php 
        $i = 0;
        function show_attachments(){
        global $post;
        while( have_posts () ){
            $i++;
            the_post();
            if ($i == 3){
            echo 'google ads code here';
            };
            $post_id = $post -> ID
            ?>
            <div class="featimg"   >
                <div class="img">
                    <?php
                    $img_src = wp_get_attachment_image_src(  $post_id  , 'full' );
                    echo '<img src="'.$img_src[0].'" alt="" />';


                    ?>
                </div>
            </div>
        <?php
        }
    }
$layout = new LBSidebarResizer( 'attachment' );
$layout -> render_frontend( 'show_attachments' );
?>
```

Can you guys help me further?

Comment: So what's the problem with your code?

Comment: It doesn't work, looks like this is not the right loop i'm looking for. I cant find the right file with the right loop for showing attached images in a single wordpress post. Any ideas how to find it?

Comment: How is this not working? Does this display the posts, but just doesn't echo your google ads? Or the loop is breaking, and none posts are shown?

Comment: It seems that this is not the loop which shows the images in my post. Even if i put a ech 'test' in the function without any condition it doesnt apear on my page.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using this in the loop, you don't need the $post global to get the id of the post. There is a built-in function for that:

```
get_the_ID();
```

With your "if" statement, you are only going to get one echo because you're seeing if $i == 3 which will only happen once. This might work in your situation most of the time, but if you had six or nine attachments and you wanted to insert the code after, it would not work.

I would recommend using the modulus operator instead and test to see if $i % 3 == 0. So if $i divided by 3 has no remainder, then echo the code.

Here's what I suggest:

```
function show_attachments(){
   $i = 1;
   global $post;
   while( have_posts () ){
      the_post();
      if ($i % 3 == 0){
         echo 'google ads code here';
      };
   ...
   $i++;
}
```

If you want to keep your $post_id variable:

```
$post_id = get_the_ID();
```

Otherwise, remove that line and change all instances to o that function.

Answer (score 0):

You were closed to it but I think you need to put the `$i` inside the function:

```
function show_attachments(){
    $i = 0;
    global $post;
...
```

Comment: That didn't work either, it seems the .php file im working in is not the right one. I need to find the file were the loop for showing attached images in a post is. Its hard, opened almost all the files :S Any ideas?